# How to run a shell script in AWS Codepipeline?

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I have a PHPproject hosted in Github and Im trying to setup a Continuous Integration using AWS Codepipeline and ElasticBeanstalk.

So far, Im able to get the repository contents from github and deploy it to ElasticBeanstalk. But I need to run a shell script before the deployment that will update a config.json file and also update a environment variable.

This is what Im trying to accomplish in the Pipeline:

1. Get the project files from Github (done)
2. Run a shell script that will update a config.json file in the project
3. Run a shell script that will set a environment variable in ElasticBeanstalk
4. Deploy to ElasticBeanstalk (done)

Any ideas of how I can get this working?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

CodePipeline doesn't support running shell in an action, but you may want to use CodeBuild, which can execute shell command to build or just update a file.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-elastic-beanstalk.html#sample-elastic-beanstalk-codepipeline

To set environment variables in ElasticBeanstalk, you can put a configuration file (.ebextensions/environmentvariables.config) in your source folder.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-methods-after.html#configuration-options-after-console-ebextensions